# Best way to fetch a route parameter with Angular

Tags: angular, url, parameters, routes, angular-activatedroute

What is the best way to take the value of my id in the current route (with ActivatedRoute or Router) ? And explain why :)

n°1

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id']
}
```

n°2

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}

ngOnInit() {
 this.id = this.router.url.includes('id')
}
```

Comment: Please define your parameters for "best" in objective terms. Opinion-based questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

It is better to subscribe to the `paramMap`

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
    this.id= params.get('id');
  });
}
```

Comment: Why it is better ? And you forgot to unsubscribe...

Comment: Good point @TimothyALCAIDE however it's left for brevity in my answer. And this is a better approach than manually iterating params or any other approach since you subscribe to the parameter map changes as it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

First declare in your constructor from ActivatedRoute from '@angular/router';

```
constructor ( private route: ActivatedRoute ){}
```

Then by using this code you will get your query params

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params =>{ let Id = params ["Id"]; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to unsubscribe from anything you subscribe to to prevent memory leaks.

```
paramsSubscription$: Subscription;
id: string;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.paramsSubscription$ = this.route.paramMap.subscribe(
    (params: ParamMap) => {
      this.id = params.get("id");
  });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  if (this.paramsSubscription$) this.paramsSubscription$.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
    const id = +params['id'];
    // more stuff
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Import Router in component.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

pass it in constructor

```
private router : Router
```

Now this will give router parameter

```
this.router.url;
```

Comment: The question is Best way to fetch a route parameter with Angular. This is not the correct answer. This returns the entire url.